# API behind Live Meeting 2007

Tags: ocs, microsoft-live-meeting

There are lots of APIs when it comes to Microsoft OCS 2007. Anyone knows what is the API behind an application like Live Meeting? UCMA 2.0?

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) - this really is a question for Microsoft, not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live meeting doesn't use UCMA 2.0 - it has its own APIs (two of them, in fact) - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905513.aspx) for an overview, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb894159.aspx) for the reference documentation for the service API (the main API for interacting with LiveMeeting)

You're right - there are a crazy amount of APIs for OCS development - see [here](https://blog.chimusoftware.com/post/overview-lync-apis/) for an overview of each.

Comment: It must be using one of the OCS APIs. The two APIs you mentioned is for Live Meeting Hosted service. Live Meeting also runs on an internal OCS installation, so it must be using at least one of the APIs.

Comment: If you're talking about the livemeeting console app i.e. the one that gets installed on your desktop, then it will be probably be using one of the client-side APIs, as opposed to UCMA 2.0. It may even build directly on top of the real-time media stack (RTMPLTFM.dll)